# Misleading geekbench score

Tags: hosting, cloud, vultr

Not sure if this is the right site to ask this question..

I was looking for a server hosting site and came across https://vultr.com/

They advertise a single-core score of 3875 on one of their cheapest cloud compute servers.

[image]

Searching for the i9-9900k processor on the [official geekbench website](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/search?q=i9+9900k) (apparently one of the top single-core cpu processors at the moment), and am finding a maximum score of 1400.

[image]

How is the single-core score of this cloud server around 3 times that of the i9-9900k processor? Is this figure different from the normal geekbench figure? Is there a way I can get a less misleading score that I can compare with other products on the geekbench website? Or is this just a mistake on Vultr's part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geekbench v4 is a different scale than v5.

Also, i9 is not a server CPU. Compare to a Skylake server SKU, Intel ARK has a long list.  Picking a [mid range silver 4114](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/search?q=silver%204114), community Geekbench v4 results vary but achieve 4,000 in presumably ideal circumstances.

(Benchmarks are problematic in general. Also test your actual workloads.)